# How to update custom fields for a user profile using Slack API - Issue with custom field update

Tags: api, slack, slack-api

I am trying to update a custom field for users in slack workspace.

Referring to API docs at - https://api.slack.com/methods/users.profile.set

My request looks like below

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $USER_TOKEN" \
-H "Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \
-d '{
    "profile": {
        "fields": {
            "Xf015PPHEJKC": {
                "value": "username-using-api",
                "alt": ""
            }
        },
        "status_text": "api-status",
        "skype": ""
    },
    "user": "U02V1UA3YHL"
}' \
https://slack.com/api/users.profile.set | jq .
```

Here `Xf015PPHEJKC` is the ID of custom field in question.

The request does not error out, it returns the user details with the old value for custom field

The above request successfully updates the `status_text` value which is not a custom field. But is unable to update the custom field value to `username-using-api`.

How can I update the custom field value using API

Answer (score 1):

the docs you linked state a few things, the first, I suspect might already be true since you are able to change one of the fields but it is worth asking:

> "You cannot change the profile details for another user unless you use a token that was generated by an Owner or Admin (For Enterprise Grid, this must be an Org Owner or Org Admin). You cannot change the profile details for a user unless both of the following are true:
> Your role level is higher than theirs. Role levels from highest to lowest are: Primary Owner > Owner > Admin > Member > Guest . More information about roles can be found here.
> For changing the profile of Owners or Admins, you must be using a token that was generated by a Primary Owner."

If this is true, great, lets look further:
When running the team.profile.get slack method, does the profile field and ID returned match the ones you posted in your question? It could be possible that the field was created in the incorrect team.

If you find that the IDs for the field do match, then you should be good there.

Reading the docs says the following:

> The fields object is an array of custom profile fields' key:value pairs.

I noticed that in your code it looks like it is not an array, but objects with a comma delimiter. I am not too familiar with CURL to say if it should be expecting those objects to be wrapped in something that denotes a list or array like [array]. If adding that type of syntax does nothing then lets continue.

What I would try would be to remove the other fields, the non-custom ones, and only try to update the custom field. The reason is that the docs mention that using "fields" object in the "profile" payload is the way to update custom fields, not non-custom fields, though I do notice you only use fields object for the custom field, but it could be that it only allows setting custom or non-custom per http request.

Their docs further go on to say that

> A field within the fields array needs a type. This determines the type of information value contains.

But their example does not show this "type" being referenced in the payload at all. It might be an additional key that is required in the payload, EXAMPLE:

```
 "profile": {
    "fields": {
        "Xf015PPHEJKC": {
            "value": "username-using-api",
            "alt": "",
            "type":"text" //Adding Type key to the field object
        }
    },
    "status_text": "api-status",
    "skype": ""
}
```

Let me know how it goes!